# How to set JRE or JDK to Java 11 for IntelliJ when I get error "compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0)..."

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-8, java-11

I try to compile https://github.com/CuriousNikhil/k5-compose in IntelliJ, I got the below error

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=61326:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/Development/experiment/k5-compose/build/classes/kotlin/main:/Users/elisha.lye/Development/experiment/k5-compose/k5-compose/build/classes/kotlin/main:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.21/6b3de2a43405a65502728047db37a98a0c7e72f0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.21.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.21/f059658740a4b3a3461aba9681457615332bae1c/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.21.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.21/2f537cad7e9eeb9da73738c8812e1e4cf9b62e4e/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.21.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.desktop/desktop-jvm/1.0.0-alpha3/7d2ec16f4e057de47d41ffc5c8416f9f85aeab3e/desktop-jvm-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.21/cc8bf3586fd2ebcf234058b9440bb406e62dfacb/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.21.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.material/material-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/60d4a46d2ee31e82ab61342887203b23aee0ba83/material-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.foundation/foundation-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/29c590b69d13ec16352497848d1bf05da1de062e/foundation-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.ui/ui-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/7f33f2592490b6d23494c0842d6f15ac592f9bb7/ui-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.ui/ui-tooling-preview-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/4676c56ea7defd68facfab054079ac1e76aba57f/ui-tooling-preview-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.runtime/runtime-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/481c6e0d45e192d4f02f993e049262e0668f6018/runtime-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-swing/1.5.0/f9702179f0e36a0541ffe77a7a62596c4fc6ad83/kotlinx-coroutines-swing-1.5.0.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.2.0/57136ff68ee784c6e19db34ed4a175338fadfde1/annotation-1.2.0.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.material/material-ripple-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/ffc54fa1f9c6e164d6ccdd53f7411bd80ccbce6c/material-ripple-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.material/material-icons-core-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/3e869bc14a82c27647e3719579d6acb517d2fc2a/material-icons-core-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.animation/animation-core-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/ec648418e6980b80f376f2b0455d5e2ba74f0445/animation-core-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.ui/ui-text-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/c1706e1e249c65fe08a672f3ab8f442ee864cf59/ui-text-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.animation/animation-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/eeff15e8d42d2fab8e6fb4eb0356ae397070aa49/animation-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.runtime/runtime-saveable-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/1b7a4801b28b5541d87cd9ae560571a77cc94dd/runtime-saveable-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.ui/ui-graphics-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/f3b1bfc01b7316e6d5af522b1025fe09f7fff137/ui-graphics-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.ui/ui-unit-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/5cefe80c330e154436abdb12825a828229ed950f/ui-unit-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.ui/ui-geometry-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/261a169b4e2816397d8c4e22e63a2d590f99210a/ui-geometry-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm/1.5.0/d8cebccdcddd029022aa8646a5a953ff88b13ac8/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.skiko/skiko-jvm/0.3.9/8b3108a3fb80baa30163d20d8176f108d895b44f/skiko-jvm-0.3.9.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.foundation/foundation-layout-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/878f19bd721b99f677e959d96595573f8198eb1c/foundation-layout-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.skiko/skiko-jvm-runtime-macos-x64/0.3.9/7dd5c3ab33897ea23d4e46251a7d04515755d0dd/skiko-jvm-runtime-macos-x64-0.3.9.jar:/Users/elisha.lye/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.compose.ui/ui-util-desktop/1.0.0-alpha3/6de31edde97babd7339e67bb1b82ebff1a805e9c/ui-util-desktop-1.0.0-alpha3.jar MainKt
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MainKt has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:601)
```

This is clearly because it needs Java 11, and it got compiled in Java 8.

However, when I check all places I see, they are all set to Java 11. The below is what I have checked

#### 1. In the Terminal environment

```
 java -version
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.50+19-CA (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.50+19-CA (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode)
elisha.lye@C02FF0VFQ05N k5-compose %
```

#### 2. In the Gradle setting

[image]

#### 3. In the Java Compiler

[image]

#### 4. In the JRE Setting

[image]

Where do I miss setting my Java Run Time?

Comment: You need one defined in "Project Structure -> Project setting "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Is for your OS and terminal, nothing common with the project

2 - Is the JDK for running Gradle. For Gradle daemon itself, not for the project

3 - Is the project's bytecode version which could be overwritten in module.

4 - Is the Runtime environment for the IDE itself.

So, you need to edit **Project Structure > Project setting > Project > Language level** See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#set-up-jdk

Answer (score 0):

1. [Edit Configurations...] or [Modify Run Configuration...] menu to open the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog.
2. Select the runtime version from the [JRE:] drop-down menu.